# Check File integrity with Hash value on Rudder

Tags: automation, rudder

someone have an idea to how to check file modification / integrity on rudder with Hash value ?

We want to create somes rules who check a lot of Hash files and raise an alert if on hash change.

Answer (score 0):

The difficult part of the problem is to be able to define a reference point for when the hash are valid. Alexis sketched a solution here:

https://www.rudder-project.org/redmine/issues/12613#note-1

With the proposed solution, you need human action only to trigger the Rudder remote execution that tell to node "these is moment to considere current hashes as correct one".